# How to have a function return a hash map owning a string?

Tags: rust, ownership

```
use std::collections::BTreeMap;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct TestStruct {
    name: String,
    num: f64,
}

fn main() {
    let test_struct = TestStruct {name: "Test".to_string(), num: 0.42 };
    println!("{:?}", test_struct);
}


fn get_fields_as_map(test_struct: &TestStruct) ->  BTreeMap<&str, &str> {
    let mut field_map: BTreeMap<&str, &str> = BTreeMap::new();
    field_map.insert("name", &test_struct.name);
    field_map.insert("num", &test_struct.num.to_string());
    field_map
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=892186e3e1a7738f6892649e792952d5)

This generates the error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
  --> src/main.rs:19:5
   |
18 |     field_map.insert("num", &test_struct.num.to_string());
   |                              --------------------------- temporary value created here
19 |     field_map
   |     ^^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

Which I think makes sense. The `to_string()` function is allocating a string whose lifetime is that of the function. What I haven't figured out is how to allocate the string such that it has the same lifetime as the `BTreeMap`. I've tried several different ways without success and feel I'm missing something. I don't fully understand ownership.

Comment: "*I don't fully understand ownership.*"—I find it easiest to ask myself "*who gets to decide when the allocation should be released?*" In this case, the string should not get deallocated unless until/someone removes it from the map and has no further use for it: so the map should own the string (until ownership is transferred to someone who removes it from the map), not merely hold a reference to it.  By inserting `&...` into the map, it only holds a reference (to a string that is dropped when the function returns, leaving a dangling pointer in the map).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can avoid the headache if you let the map *own* the strings inside it rather than store references. References mean lifetimes are involved, and as you've found it's difficult to construct `&str`s with the required lifetimes.

Change the `&str` references to owned `String`s and life is easy:

```
fn get_fields_as_map(test_struct: &TestStruct) ->  BTreeMap<String, String> {
    let mut field_map = BTreeMap::new();
    field_map.insert("name".to_owned(), test_struct.name.to_owned());
    field_map.insert("num".to_owned(), test_struct.num.to_string());
    field_map
}
```